# How can i get 2 classes by id inside the same function

Tags: javascript, css

I need to target two div elements and toggle their classes simultanouesly.

I understand that I can get multiple divs "by ID" by using `.querySelectorAll`

but when I get to `.classlist.toggle ("NewClassName");` how can I target two classes??

So here's some code:

```css
#small-div{
    background-color:#aaaaaa;
    border: 3px solid #aaaaaa;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: auto 10px auto auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.tobetoggled{
    width: 45%;
    float: left;
}

#small-div2{
    background-color:#aaaaaa;
    border: 3px solid #aaaaaa;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: auto 10px auto auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.tobetoggled2{
    width: 45%;
    float: right;
}

.toggletothis{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    z-index: 100;
}

.toggletothis2{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    z-index: 100;
}

.whensmalldivistoggled{           
    display: none;

}/* when small-div is clicked, small-div toggles to class "tobetoggled" while small-div 2 simultaneously toggles to class "whensmalldivistoggled" (the display none class) */
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="tobetoggled" onclick="function()" id="small-div">
  </div> 

  <div class="tobetoggled2" onclick="separatefunction()" id="small-div2">
  </div> 

</div> <!-- end container -->

<script>
function picClicktwo() {
    document.querySelectorAll("small-div, small-div2").classList.toggle("toggletothis, whensmalldivistoggled");

}
</script>
```

So as you can see one div is on the right, the other is on the left, each set to 45% width. So if I toggle one div to 100% width the browser still respects the other divs space instead of taking the whole 100%.

So I'm thinking if I can get the div on the right ,for example, to not display when the div on the left is toggled, it will be out of the way so the left div can take all 100%

Maybe im going about this the wrong way. Any help is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Note that `document.querySelectorAll("small-div, small-div2").classList` is `undefined`, because `.querySelectorAll()` returns a *list*, not an individual DOM element. And if you want to select by id you need `"#small-div, #small-div2"`.

Comment: so is what im asking possible to do??

Comment: If selecting with `.querySelectorAll()` you just need a loop to process the returned items one at a time with `.classList.toggle()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a single javascript function that sets appropriate classes on each element.  Since you have only two elements it is not too complex.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="lefty" onclick="toggle('lefty', 'righty')">Lefty</div>
  <div id="righty" onclick="toggle('righty', 'lefty')">Righty</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function toggle(target, other)
{
    var t = document.getElementById(target);
  var o = document.getElementById(other);
    if (!t.className || t.className == "inative")
  {
    t.className = "active";
    o.className = "inactive";
  }
  else
  {
    t.className = "";
    o.className = "";
  }
}
```

CSS

```
#container {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding: 15px 0;
}
#container div {
  color: white;
  width: 45%;
  display: inline-block;
}
#lefty {
  background-color: blue;
}
#righty {
  background-color: purple;
}
#container div.active {
  width: 90%;
}
#container div.inactive {
  display:none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dLbu9odf/1/

This could be made more elegant or capable of handling more elements with something like `toggle(this)` and then some DOM traversal and iteration in javascript, but that's a bit beyond scope.  If that were the case I would recommend jQuery.